# I think my Apple ID was hacked, changed my password twice but failed, what to do?

Tags: iphone, icloud, security, apple-id, password

I just had the weirdest thing happen on my iPhone 6s. I'm running iOS 10.0.2 and while I was sitting in my office, my phone lit up stating that a location in China is trying to access my Apple ID, I denied the access, but shortly after my phone started acting really crazy. No weird text messages or anything, but my iCloud/Apple ID was locked, I changed my password twice and tried to sign back in after unlocking and no luck. My location services also drained my battery in about 20 minutes from 98% to 39%.

What is going on? What should I do to reset everything and get my phone back to normal?

Comment: If you have been locked out of your iCloud account by a hacker, you need to 1) watch the transactions of or cancel any credit cards linked to that account and 2) contact Apple. You should be able to prove you're the owner of the account (billing address can be verified with a utility bill or similar). Apple should be able to shut out the hacker and return the account to you. I don't know that they can - try asking Apple. Apple's customer support is generally pretty good.

Comment: @NoahL Canceling your credit cards is an extreme step that is almost certainly unnecessary. There's no way to view the full credit card number of a stored card, either through the Apple Store or any of the iTunes stores, so it would only work for purchasing items in one of those stores. You should easily be able to determine if anything was purchased at the Apple Store through order history.

Comment: @tubedogg they may be able to make purchases from Apple using the card. That's what I meant. It's easier for the credit card company to send you a new card then dealing with them about fraudulent purchases

Comment: @OP, What are you basing the location services draining the battery on? Even if it was accessing it constantly, there's no way it would drop that fast that quickly. Also, even if someone had access to your Apple ID, without physical access to the device, there's nothing that they could do that would cause location services to chew through the battery like that, even if that were possible.

Comment: @NoahL Not really. You then have to go change your CC number(s) everywhere it's stored, go change all recurring transactions to use the new number(s), be out of use of the card(s) while they're being sent to you (which may not be too bad for a credit card, but for a debit card it could be crippling), etc. as opposed to filling out a form for a fraudulent charge, getting a provisional credit, and waiting while they determine it was fraud. Or call Apple, have them lock the account, and ask them if there were any recent purchases...

Comment: ... The ones that would matter would be the Apple Store, due to the price, and Apple doesn't ship THAT quickly that at this point they wouldn't be able to cancel any orders made in the last few hours, or in an extreme case recall a shipment they already sent out.

Comment: @tubedogg ok I guess that makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you contact Apple support immediately, and watch for any fraudulent purchases on the Apple Store and iTunes stores.

These links may be of help to you: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204145 (Apple support page for if you think your Apple ID has been compromised) and https://support.apple.com/contact (to contact Apple support).

Hope this helps!